# Guice -How to inject dependency inside the class which is extending Abstract module - Java

Tags: java, guice, guice-3

I have to trigger ***TestDriver.startPoller()*** from ***EnvironmentModule*** since EnvironmentModule is extending from Abstractmodule I am not sure how to inject dependency inside ***EnvironmentModule*** is it even possible ?.  If not how do I trigger  ***TestDriver.startPoller()*** from ***EnvironmentModule***

```
@Log4j2
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
public class TestDriver {

    private ClientTrafficCalculator clientTrafficCalculator;
    private TaskAllocator taskAllocator;


    @SneakyThrows
    public void startPoller() {


        new Thread(clientTrafficCalculator::prepareRateLimiterForAllClients).start();
        new Thread(taskAllocator::processPendingRecordsInDDB).start();
        log.info("All threads are started");

    }

}
```

***Environment module***

```
    @Log4j2
    @AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
    public class EnvironmentModule extends AbstractModule {
    
        private TestDriver testDriver;
    
    
        @SneakyThrows
        public EnvironmentModule(final String[] args) {
    
            marketplace = System.getProperty("realm", "USTest");
            final String realm = getPropOrDefault("realm", "USTest");
            final String root = getPropOrDefault("root", ".");
            AppConfig.initialize(SERVICE_NAME, null, appConfigArgs);

            TestDriver.startPoller(); 
    
        }

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        install(new TomcatContainerModule(new ServiceModule(Test)));
    }
}
```

Expected :

`TestDriver.startPoller();` // this works fine

Current result

`TestDriver.startPoller();` // thorwing null pointer exception because it is not getting injected and **TestDriver** is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found an answer we can do something as below

```
@Log4j2
public class TestDriver extends AbstractModule {


    @Override
    public void configure() {
        requestInjection(this);
    }

    @Inject
    public void startPoller(ClientTrafficCalculator clientTrafficCalculator,
        TaskAllocator taskAllocator, PManager pManager) {

        new Thread(pManager::name).start();
      
    }


}
```

And we have to install that, installing will trigger that method

```
install(new TestDriver()); //trigger pollers for proxy and task allocation
```

Thanks
Jk